# update query in postgrel RDS on aws

Tags: javascript, sql, postgresql, amazon-web-services

“42703” or “Column does not exist”
[Understanding the issue](https://www.paessler.com/help/postgre-sql-errors)

I have trying to update the table RDS specific to postgrel with by inserting new attribute in class object.
The data would something like this after inserting or updating :

"class" : { "isPresent" : false }

```
Details :
Database : postgrel
Table name : student
Attributes for table :  student_id, class
"class" attribute is of object type
```

This query works on my machine

```
update "student" set "class" = jsonb_set("class"::jsonb, '{isPresent}','false', true) WHERE "student_id" =1
```

When I'm trying to do the same query, on aws postgrel it does not work and throws an error
query :

```
{
  "query": "update student set class = jsonb_set('\"student.class\"'::jsonb, '{isPresent}','false', true) WHERE '\"student.student_id\"' = 1"                                  
}
```

Error :

```
"column \"class\" of relation \"student\" does not exist"
```

When tried this, gives syntax erro :

```
{
   "query": "update '\"student\"' set '\"class\"' = jsonb_set('\"student.class\"'::jsonb, '{isPresent}','false', true) WHERE '\"student.student_id\"' = 1"                                  
    }
```

I think the issue is syntax error : [postgrel quotes syntax](https://www.prisma.io/dataguide/postgresql/short-guides/quoting-rules)
but have no idea how can I use double quotes under doble quotes

Comment: Eliminate all double quotes on all database references - table names, column names, etc. Postgres never requires them, unless you use them in the definition, then always requires them. That is if your obfuscation manager (javascript?) allows it.  You seem to be escaping for that `not for Postgres`, to allow passing the double quotes. Eliminating the need to pass them eliminates the need to escape them.

Comment: Never heard of "Postgrel". Are you talking about Postgres?